# Django REST FRAMEWORK, How can I create a custom URL linking a nested List

Tags: django, rest, frameworks

Referring to the Django Rest Framework tutorial app:

https://github.com/tomchristie/rest-framework-tutorial

Referring to the users page, that is:

domain/port/snippets/users/

The response is as follows, in my case:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "count": 2, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "domain/port/snippets/users/1/", 
            "username": "super", 
            "snippets": [
                "domain/port/snippets/1/", 
                "domain/port/snippets/3/"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "url": "domain/port/snippets/users/2/", 
            "username": "super2", 
            "snippets": [
                "domain/port/snippets/4/"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have been trying to do is to somehow replace the "snippets" list with a single URL that links to a page for user1_snippets in the case of the first user and to a page for user2's snippets in the case of user 2...

By "snippets list", I'm referring to this chunk of text (which could be long) :             "snippets": [
                "domain/port/snippets/1/", 
                "domain/port/snippets/3/"
            ]

So I just need to get the framework to produce something like the following code:

```
<a href="domain:port/snippets/user/1">snippets</a>
 <a href="domain:port/snippets/user/2">snippets</a>
```

Then it will be really easy to develop the matching url conf and view.

The reason I want to do this is that in my own app, my analogous 'snippets' are very large in number, so I think it would be sensible to group them - on a separate page - for one (analogous) user. Then I can have the "user" page just for discovery of users. It will be quick to load, easy to interpret etc.

I know the answer lies in the documentation below, and I'll get there eventually but a few pointers would be really helpful.

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section on so called "Hyperlinking" in the tutorial:

http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis.html

and as you said, you need to look for `HyperlinkedIdentityField` in the relations article.

So your serializer could look like this:

```
class HyperlinkedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-list')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('snippets')
```

Then the url is resolved using the provided 'snippet-list' view_name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though I didn't do it this way in the end. I have a horrible hack based on over-riding the "to_native" function of HyperLinkedModelSerizlier and I appended the URL to the set of serialized fields.